# mysql selecting multiple rows in key value pair

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table like below:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id | uid | key        | value
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1  | u01 | instrument | guitar
2  | u01 | level_____ | 10
3  | u02 | instrument | guitar
4  | u02 | level_____ | 1
```

Now I want to perform a query which searches for: 
All UID whose can play both guitar and has a level of 10
and the result should show as :

Result >

```
uid : u01
```

But I am kinda stuck, and don't know what should be the query like. 
I know that I might have to perform a conditional aggregate, but can please someone guide me

Comment: guess. i have to figure it out on my own..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT UID FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE IN ('PIANO', 'VIOLIN')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select uid
from your_table
where `key` = 'instrument'
and `value` in ('guitar','violin')
group by uid
having count(distinct `value`) = 2
```